# How to create model with an array field which contains another documents as an embedded documents in Mongodb (Mongoid)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, mongodb, geospatial, mongoid4

I am using Rails 4 with Mongoid for an event based application. 
I am trying to create a model where I want to add an array field with embedded documents in that array. This embedded documents will contain user's geo coordinate and timestamp. After every 5 minutes I will be pushing user's latest coordinates to user's (location) array. can someone please help me, How can i create that.

My sample model and desired documents are as below.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String

  field :locations, type: Array

end
```

Here I want to push

Here is sample document that I am looking for as a result:

```
{ _id : ObjectId(...),
  name : "User_name",
  locations : [ {
                 _id : ObjectID(...),
                 time : "...." ,
                 loc : [ 55.5, 42.3 ]
                } ,
                {
                 _id : ObjectID(...),
                 time : "...",
                 loc : [ -74 , 44.74 ]
                }
              ]
}
```

I was able to add the value in location array without embedded document through IRB, but as I will be using MongoDB's Geospatial queries later on, so I want to use 2D indexes and rest of the stuff Mongo Documentation mentioned.
Hence I believe it needs to have array of documents which contain the latitude & longitude. which will also save my time to code.

Also can I make the time of the location as documents '_id' ? (It can help me to reduce the query overhead)

I would really appriciate if someone can help me with the structure of model i should write or guide me to the references.

P.S: Let me know if you suggest some extra references/help about storing geospatial data in mongoDB which can be helpful for me.

Comment: Just moving quickly aside from the model definition, placing co-ordinates inside an array for geospatial queries is not a great idea. While queries will work, it's not easy to tell "which" entries in the array matched or were "near" the conditions given. This is one case where the data is often better off in a different collection. Maybe you should ask some questions about your expected query patterns to get a better idea how to model first.

Comment: @NeilLunn If i create a different collection for location and then embed it in user document will it work?, I am afraid the user document will become too large to handle. This is my first time to work with NoSQL, as I am using it to improve the performance plus it would be an easy API for location based application. I am expecting to get user's coordinate every now and then and number of users will be in thousands. I expect to find users as close as possible to 1-3 meters so that i can map them. Whats your thoughts on it?

Comment: As was the general point of my comment, it might help you to try posting some questions here and/or on other lists explaining parts of what you are trying to do. Generally in NoSQL you work on the problem first and then get to what the optimal data-model is rather than the other way around. This question really just asks how to code up the model in mongoid.

Comment: @NeilLunn Oh,I've a rough algorithm for the things which i need to do and show as a result of my project. I will work on the psudo code/queries so that I can ask direct questions. For general what I can say is: I will be targeting crowd of thousands of people, and monitor them in certain area. They will be moving coordinates but I have to search at least 3 users (neighbours) around each other at any given time. If not the user is not in my radar. At the end in parallel, I have to get the list of last standing users from my given location. This list of users are my results which keep changing.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help somebody.

If you want to embed documents you can use `embedded_many` feature of mongoid, which handles such relations. It allows you to define index on embedded documents as well

http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#embeds_many

Mongoid points out, that 2D indexes should be applied to arrays:
http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/indexing.html

In your case models may look like this:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String

  embeds_many :locations

  index({ "locations.loc" => "2d" })

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations # see http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/nested_attributes.html#common
end

class Location
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :time, type: DateTime # see http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html#fields
  field :loc, type: Array

  embedded_in :user
end
```

But beware of using `update` and nested attributes - it allows you only update attributes, but not delete or reject them. It's preferrable to use `(association)_attributes=` methods instead:

```
@user = User.new({ name: 'John Doe' })
@user.locations_attributes = {
  "0" => {
   _id : ObjectID(...),
   time : "...." ,
   loc : [ 55.5, 42.3 ]
  } ,
  "1" => {
   _id : ObjectID(...),
   time : "...",
   loc : [ -74 , 44.74 ]
  }
}
@user.save!
```

Comment: New full link for relationship: [docs.mongodb.com](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/6.1.0/mongoid-relations/#embeds-many)